# Create a keyboard shortcut that only listens to the command key on macOS

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I create a keyboard shortcut only for the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key? `UIKeyCommand`'s initializer also expects a nonnull regular key (`input`) along the modifier flag(s) (<kbd>cmd</kbd> in my case) so it doesn't work when passing `nil`.

I know it's possible as Paste and Slack are doing the same, but I don't have experience with macOS to figure it out.

This is **not** a duplicate of [Detect any key press, including modifier keys, on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22887085/865175) because that question is weirdly worded and it ranks low on Google. I searched for days for an answer to this question and couldn't find any, so I'd leave this open for easier finding.

Comment: @CraigSiemens, See my edit...

Comment: Have you tried the answer in the proposed duplicate? If it works, we can leave it as already answered and make this question attract more search hits. The duplicate question can also be edited for clarity, if it helps.

Comment: @E_net4, You say that you can leave it open yet there are 3 close votes.

Comment: I did not say that. Questions closed as duplicates are not immediately subjected to a possible deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using:

```c
[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskFlagsChanged handler:^NSEvent *(NSEvent *incomingEvent) {
    if (incomingEvent.modifierFlags & NSEventModifierFlagCommand) {
        NSLog(@"command key down");
    }

    return incomingEvent;
}];
```